# get not retrieving name attribute from object

Tags: backbone.js

From the backbone docs

```
getmodel.get(attribute) 
Get the current value of an attribute from the model. For example: note.get("title")
```

I seeded some data with a name for each country into a Rails app

```
Country.create!(name: "Brazil")
Country.create!(name: "France")
Country.create!(name: "Germany")
Country.create!(name: "Spain")
```

In the console, I created a new collection and fetched the data

```
countries.fetch();
Object
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:3000/countries".
```

Checked the length. Equal to the four countries I created.

```
countries.length
4
```

Selected a random one using underscore's shuffle method.

```
c = countries.shuffle()[0]
```

The object has a name

```
  Backbone.Model
_changes: Array[2]
_currentAttributes: Object
_events: Object
_hasComputed: false
_previousAttributes: Object
attributes: Object
  country: Object
   created_at: "2013-01-07T06:09:43Z"
   id: 2
   name: "France"
   updated_at: "2013-01-07T06:09:43Z"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

Tried to get the name attribute from the object several different ways, all without success

```
c.get('name')
undefined
c.get("name");
undefined
c.get("name")
undefined
```

Can anyone think what I might be doing wrong?

One thing that I find unusual is that there is a 'country' attribute wrapping the other attributes

```
attributes: Object
      country: Object
       created_at: "2013-01-07T06:09:43Z"
       id: 2
       name: "France"
       updated_at: "2013-01-07T06:09:43Z"
```

I'm not sure why 'country' is wrapping the other data. Is it because I created the seed data with a Country model?

```
Country.create!(name: "Brazil")
```

anyways, `obj.get('country')` *doesn't* return undefined

```
c = countries.shuffle()[0]
k = c.get('country')
Object
 created_at: "2013-01-07T06:09:43Z"
 id: 3
 name: "Germany"
 updated_at: "2013-01-07T06:09:43Z"
 __proto__: Object
```

but I can't do a get on the name after that (i.e after I did the get on country)

```
k = c.get('country')
Object
k.get('name')
undefined
```

Is there a way to remove the country wrapper and just be able to do get on the attributes that it was created with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override [`model.parse`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse) to extract the `country` element. Backbone calls `parse` before populating the model from fetched data:

```
var Country = Backbone.Model.extend({
  parse: function(attributes) {
    return attributes.country;
  }
});
```

Comment: that works, but what happens if you don't declare a model for the collection, which I don't believe you are required to do. and is that something new, I don't recall seeing that (for example, that step wasn't taken in a Railscast on backbone)

Comment: thanks, threw this in ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = false